# Strange behavior of SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am using `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date result = sdf.parse("20221114-12:34:56.789");
```

Works fine for the above example (result: `Mon Nov 14 12:34:56 CET 2022`), but works strange for obvious erroneous input:

- `123-20221114-12:34:56.789` -> `Sun Feb 15 12:34:56 CET 728`
- `12320221114-12:34:56.789` -> `Mon Nov 21 12:34:56 CET 1289`

I would expect to throw `ParseException` in these cases.

Note that the timestamp is input and the format cannot be changed.

As a cross-check I tried this: `abc-20221114-12:34:56.789`, and at least in this case it threw `ParseException`.

Comment: What is your question? Also, please stop using `SimpleDateFormat`, and use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: Note that this class and `Date` are legacy. Instead, use the stuff from `java.time`. In this case probably a `DateTimeFormatter` with a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: I wouldnt be too surprised with bugs and bad behavior of the old legacy classes. One of the reasons they have been superseded and nobody uses them anymore.

Comment: Don't ever use the legacy date library, instead, you can use modern `java.time`, for example:

`DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    LocalDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse("20221114-12:34:56.789", dateTimeFormatter);`

Note, this will throw `DateTimeParseException` and not `ParseException`.

Comment: You can use whatever you like. It's up to YOU but...this sort of thing is what you can expect from old antique libraries. **Date** and **SimpleDateFormat** are pretty well known to be buggy.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` takes `123-20221114` to mean year 123, month -2 (minus 2) and day of month 221114. It doesn’t disturb it that this is complete nonsense. Similarly `12320221114` is day 21114 of month 2 of year 1232. Yes, this is how confusing `SimpleDateFormat` is.Stay far away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SimpleDateFormat` contains bugs. In the example posted the interpretations are the following:

- `123-20221114-12:34:56.789`: year 123, month -2, day 221114
- `12320221114-12:34:56.789`: year 1232, month 02, day 21114

Actually this answers the original question. And as a suggestion the `java.time` module should be used introduced in Java 8, as described in other comments.

Answer (score 1):

The terrible `SimpleDateFormat` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes , specifically `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuuMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS" );
LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.parse( "20221114-12:34:56.789" , f );
```